# Entity Framework 4: How to code projection to a class type?

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4, projection

If I have a class like the following:

```
public class Customer {
    public int    id    {get;set;}
    public string name  {get;set;}
    public string line1 {get;set;}
    public string line2 {get;set;}
    public string line3 {get;set;}
    public string line4 {get;set;}
}
```

And I only want to select the ID and Name values, leaving the rest null.

```
var myCustomerList = DC.Customer.Select( 
                     p => new Customer { id = p.id, name = p.name });
```

I get the following error:

```
The entity or complex type 'MyModel.Customer' cannot
be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.
```

How else would you do it?  Am I required to specify all the Class's fields?

Comment: Did you find a good solution to your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var myCustomerList = from c in DC.Customer 
                     select new { id = p.id, name = p.name };
```

The above will create an [Anonymous Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx).

Practical Application:

"var myCustomerList" <-- Anonymous Type.

An anonymous type with two properties "id" and "name". Also, "var" lets you create an Implicitly typed local variable. This means:

a) You didn't have to declare/write a class structure to hold a type with only those two properties;

b) You don't have to maintain that either - you can change the structure of the above query, and "it just works".

Comment: Say you want to return the strongly typed object where the rest of the fields are null?  I used your advice, then looped through the anonymous object feeding a new List<Customer> so my repository didn't need a ton of ViewModel classes defined.

Comment: I looped through the records because I am not always sure how many fields will be in the domain model (if they add more).

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to create a CustomerInfo type:

```
public class CustomerInfo
{
  public int Id { get; set;}
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

You can't map two types directly to the same table in EF but you can easily create a view for your info type and then map to that:

```
CREATE VIEW vwCustomerInfo AS SELECT Id, Name FROM Customer
```

You then map your CustomerInfo type to your view:

```
public class CustomerInfoMap : EntityConfiguration<CustomerInfo>
{
  public CustomerInfoMap()
  {
    .ToTable("vwCustomerInfo");
  }
}
```

A side-effect of this is that EF will only retrieve the columns in the view when querying your database. When retrieving a CustomerInfo by id you'll get SQL like this:

> SELECT Id, Name FROM vwCustomers WHERE id = 1

In addition, as long as your view is updatable you can update your CustomerInfo type from EF and the underlying table will be updated.